# Flutter Mobile Webview Iframe with keyboard falsely reloads screen

Tags: flutter, dart, iframe, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

When i load an iframe using the webview_flutter package, and click on an input field the screen refreshes and the keyboard never appears. The Iframe itself functions normally as expected, except when clicking a field that invokes the keyboard.

Sample code to replicate:

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class PaymentWebView extends StatefulWidget {
  static const path = "payments-web-view";
  final String url;
  const PaymentWebView({super.key, required this.url});

  @override
  State<PaymentWebView> createState() => _PaymentWebViewState();
}

class _PaymentWebViewState extends State<PaymentWebView> {
  final controller = WebViewController()
    ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000));
  // ..setNavigationDelegate(
  //   NavigationDelegate(
  //     onProgress: (int progress) {
  //       // Update loading bar.
  //     },
  //     onPageStarted: (String url) {},
  //     onPageFinished: (String url) {},
  //     onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
  //     onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
  //       return NavigationDecision.navigate;
  //     },
  //   ),
  // );

  @override
  void initState() {
    Future.microtask(() {
      final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
      final height = (size.height * 0.7).toInt().toString();
      final width = (size.width * 0.9).toInt().toString();
      controller.loadRequest(Uri.dataFromString('''<html>
            <head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></head><iframe src="${widget.url}" height=${height}px width=${width}px ></iframe></html>''',
          mimeType: 'text/html'));

    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Refreshed webview");
    return Scaffold(
      body: WebViewWidget(controller: controller),
    );
  }
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by moving the controller initialization to the initState:

```dart
class _YourScreen extends State<YourScreen> {
  final String _url;

  final WebViewController _controller = WebViewController();
  _YourScreen(this._url);
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(Colors.grey[100]!)
/////// other code ........
}
```